# Sort a TreeMap if the key is date

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, treemap

What comparator should I use to sort a `TreeMap<Date, Long>` if I want its keys to be "the same" if they hold the same DAY.
What I'm trying to say is that I want "15.09.2022 at 12:00" and "15.09.2022 at 12:01" to be the same.

I came up with an idea

```
Map<Date, Long> map = new TreeMap<>((date1, date2) -> {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    return fmt.format(date1).compareTo(fmt.format(date2));
});
```

But it isn't quite the best practice to cast `Date`s to `String`s every time. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `Date`, which is a bit outdated anyway?

Comment: `Date` is legacy, since Java 8 we have `LocalDateTime` and other classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Are you using `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to `java.time`, then trim off the local time.

```
new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(
  date -> date.toInstant()
    .atZone(APPROPRIATE_TIMEZONE)
    .toLocalDate()))
```

(Or, better, use `java.time` in the first place.)

Replace `APPROPRIATE_TIMEZONE` with a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object for [a time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Note that you absolutely need a time zone; two `java.util.Date`s can represent different days depending on which timezone you interpret them in.  (Confused?  Yes, it's confusing.  This is why `java.util.Date` got replaced with something clearer.)

Answer (score -2):

Call `.getTime()` and integer divide it by `1000*60*60*24` (1000 milliseconds, 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours):

```
Date date = new Date();
Long dateDayKey = date.getTime() / 86_400_000L;
```

This will "chop off" the part of less resolution than a day. (`getTime()` gives you the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00)

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm aware of that, but I didn't want to answer a question that wasn't asked or do a code review. The question was asked with `java.util.Date` so I was under the impression that this is what is available to work with. Conversion to another class for this task (!) would not make anything better.

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.